# Trigger a sub-pipeline inside a pipeline in Azure yaml pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there a way to trigger a pipeline in a pipeline in Azure pipelines, wait for the triggered pipeline to finish and then continue with the original pipeline? I only know how to trigger another pipeline if the first finishes.

Pipeline A:

- Setup and do some stuff
- Pass parameters and trigger pipeline B, wait for it to finish and get artifacts
- Pass parameters and trigger pipeline C, wait for it to finish and get artifacts
- Pass parameters and trigger pipeline D, wait for it to finish and get artifacts
- Continue with pipeline A using artifacts from pipelines B - D

**Reason**: Pipeline A is an installer pipeline that requires build artifacts from various pipelines before it can continue creating an installer. Also would like to pass different parameters to pipelines (build configuration, some library paths, etc...).

Comment: Hi Name; it is possible, but it isn't simple. We've implemented such a thing, which I've described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75814229/174843.
Does that answer help?